# formulate brain teaser as calculus rates problem:

Tags: calculus

I recently was asked the $2$ ropes question:  Given two non-homogenous ropes (i.e. length to burn time not constant), with total burn time $=60$, how can you measure $45$ seconds?

I'd like to formulate this as a difference of cdf's for $n$-number ropes($n$), each with any total known burn time($b$), to measure any given time $T$.

I've tried grouping number of ropes by burn time and summing the exponentials to $T$.

$$ e^{n_1b_1} + e^{n_2b_2} + .. + e^{n_{n}b_{n}} = T $$

But am unclear as to how to relate the sums, i.e. how do I difference the cdfs of burn-rates with respect to length to get $T$ ?
Is cdf even the way to do this?

Comment: I deleted my answer since you said you already knew it. (You might have pointed that out right away.) You may want to take a look at [fusible numbers](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5614v1.pdf).